# How to close window in browser with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, window

I have:

```
var myWindow;
    $('#facebook').click(function(){
        myWindow = window.open(this.href, "myWindowName", "width=800, height=600");
        return false;
});
```

but now when I try:

```
myWindow.close();
```

I get:
VM156:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: my is not defined(…)

Why? How to solve this problem?

Comment: The error message says "my" is not defined? As compared to "myWindow"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need Javascript to do this. Use **`window.close()`**:

```
close();
```

Note: the current window is implied. This is equivalent:

```
window.close();
```

or you can specify a different window.

**So:**

```
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    close();
  }
}
```

**with HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">close</a>
```

**or:**

```
<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">close</a>
```

Comment: OP isn't trying to close the *current* window. And the code in the question shows he is already trying to use the close() method.

Comment: i updated my answer .. please check `Full Example`. It will work for you.

Comment: I don't see what is different in your updated code than in the code already in the question.